# URL.getContent wrong encoding

Tags: java, linux, io

I have a URL that i am trying to write to a file on a linux box.
I can do a

```
      wget http://localhost/fileIwant.text
```

and everything is fine.

when I try to use Java's URL like this:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/fileIwant.text");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    File file = new File(path+filename);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //use FileWriter to write file
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(inputLine);
    }
```

I have tried every permutation of readers, streams, byte[] that I can think of, but i still get a file that has the diamond ?  in them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream in=(new URL("http://localhost/fileIwant.text")).openStream();
```